# How do you say « the desired star » in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would you say « the desired star » (with star being an actual star, like in the cosmos) in Latin, or is there a catchy phrase matching with « desideratus » or talking about a great regret/loss of a star ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! When you say "star", do you mean a literal star in the cosmos or star in the sense of a celebrity, musician, etc?

Comment: Thanks! I meant a star in the cosmos

Comment: Hi CharlyM, I'm still not quite sure what you mean. Can you expand on your question a bit? I have an idea, but clearer questions yield clearer answers. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, in school we once talked about a Latin word (or a sentence I can’t remember) that was about desire and meant something like the regret of a lost star or of loosing a star (the star in the cosmos). I sought on the internet and end up with « desiderus sideris » but I’m not sure it’s a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: Some etymologies connect *dēsīderō* ("desire") with sīdus ("heavenly body/star/constellation") in a perhaps plausible, but convoluted way.  Could that be the basis for your recollection of a link between "desire" and "star"?

Comment: Yes I think it could be that

Comment: I am almost sure when we talk about desire in philosophy class the teacher linked it with a Latin word (or a sentence) that could mean « the sorrow over a lost star ». So I guess « desire » and « star » are linked. 
Could « desideratus sideris » be the right translation and a grammatically correct one ?